# "column ambiguously defined error" even when the column is prefixed?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have the following sql and it works fine (Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production).

```
with n as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, high.Id
from    (select distinct NT from n) n 
        outer apply (
           select * 
           from n x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id
        ) low
        outer apply (
           select * 
           from (select * from n x where x.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
        ) high
```

Now I changed it to the following,

```
with n as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, phigh.Id -- Error - phigh.Id
from    (select distinct NT from n) n 
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from n x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id
        ) low
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from (select * from n x where x.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
        ) high
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from (select * from n x where x.NT = n.NT-1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
        ) phigh
```

Now it gets the following error on `phigh.Id`:

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>
> 918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"

And the second query works if I change `phigh.Id` to `phigh.*`? Changing `phigh.Id` to `high.Id` works too.

### Update:

Tried to use the different alias from the CTE. Still got the same error

```
with n as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, phigh.Id -- Error - phigh.Id
from    (select distinct NT from n) nt 
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from n x where x.NT = nt.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id
        ) low
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from (select * from n x where x.NT = nt.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
        ) high
        outer apply (
            select * 
            from (select * from n x where x.NT = nt.NT-1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
        ) phigh
```

### Update2:

The following testable query got the error.

```
with t as (
  select 10 as cnt, 1 as Id from dual
), 
x as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, 
        high.Id a, 
        phigh.Id
from    (select distinct NT from x) n 
        outer apply (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id) low
        outer apply (select * from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) high
        outer apply (select * from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT - 1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) phigh
```

The following code works.

```
with t as (
  select 10 as cnt, 1 as Id from dual
), 
x as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, 
        --high.Id a, 
        phigh.Id
from    (select distinct NT from x) n 
        outer apply (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id) low
        --outer apply (select * from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) high
        outer apply (select * from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT - 1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) phigh
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use different aliases for main query and cte and now they are the same `n`:

```
with n_cte as (
    select /*+ materialize*/ ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from tab
)
select  n.NT, phigh.Id 
from    (select distinct NT from n_cte) n 
outer apply (
    select * 
    from n_cte where n.NT = n_cte.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id
) low
outer apply (
    select * 
    from (select * from n_cte where n_cte.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
) high
outer apply (
    select * 
    from (select * from n_cte where n_cte.NT = n.NT-1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1
) phigh
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=403d520104165a2f646d7096ff0eba39)**

Another option could be adding `SELECT /*+ materialize*/ ...` hint inside cte part.

Comment: I updated the query but I still get the same error.

Comment: Let me see. I guess the t table is a dummy one. Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production`

Comment: `t` is another cte with three tables inner joined.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Please check revised version

Comment: I still have the error. I found it works if I remove the subquery of `high`.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Yes, I saw similar case before. Does materialize hint change anything? If not you could use `CTEATE TABLE temp AS ....` and refer to physically materialized table

Comment: How to add materialized hint in oracle? I cannot create temp table because the code needs to be in a view.

Comment: @ca9163d9 I already provided an example. Use it on your SELECT list in place where you have multiple joins.

Comment: Tried to put `/*+ materialize*/` inside my `t` CTE and no luck.

Comment: I posted some comments as an answer. But it really doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: @ca9163d9 Are you sure you have the newest updates installed?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not the owner of the oracle server. I found another way to work around the problem. It's a bug.

Comment: @ca9163d9 If it is a bug then as you see it was fixed in 18c. You should really check if you are running up-to-date version, otherwise creating workaround is not the best possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found renaming the column names shared in `high` and 'phigh` works.

```
with t as (
  select 10 as cnt, 1 as Id from dual
), 
x as (
    select ntile(cnt) over ( partition by cnt order by Id ) NT, Id
    from t
)
select  n.NT, 
        high.Id a, 
        phigh.Id
from    (select distinct NT from x) n 
        outer apply (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id) low
        outer apply (select Id z from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) high
        outer apply (select * from (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT - 1 order by Id desc) d where rownum = 1) phigh
```

But it's really not a solution for me (the question owner). The code will be dynamically generated and there will be many columns.

It seems Oracle has an issue when multiple subqueries return columns with the same name and these columns are in the select clause.

### Solution 2:

Changing `outer apply (select * from x where x.NT = n.NT and rownum = 1 order by Id) low` to `outer apply (select * from x where x.NT = 1 and rownum = 1 order by Id) low` will also get rid of the error.